# Merge two fields before posting to MySQL

Tags: mysql, drupal, drupal-webform

Any help and/or direction you can give me will be greatly appreciated.

My site has drupal 7 installed and a bunch of plug-ins. I am using a third party web hosting site.

On my website, I have a webform that submits a several member info. When this information is submitted, it gets submitted into, what appears to me, as a default form submission data table on mysql. I guess I have a two part question.

First, I would like my webform to be submitted in a custom table so that webform, contacts and etc have their own database table.

Secondly, I would like to merge two columns together to form a unique user email on my site. For instance, in my webform, the first field is a 'State' dropdown list where the user has to choose the state they are in. And the second field, they have to type in a user specific info. So when they choose the state and fill in their unique user info, I would like to combine these two columns to create an email address, e.g. unique_user_info@fl.mysite.com.

oh, btw, I put the values in state dropdown to add state-specific info. in other words, if the member chooses 'Florida' then it adds, @fl.mysite.com and chooses 'California', it adds @ca.mysite.com

Once again, your help on this will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: *****Update***** I just, accidentaly, ran into a module called 'mysql views'. This module did exactly what I needed to on my first question. So I just need to figure out how i need to solve the 2nd question.

Comment: **Update** OK. So, I've been reading up on sql commands and I've found 'concat' command that does what I want. So.. I ran the following command in mysql "SELECT concat( unique_user_info, State ) 
FROM my_database_table" and it combined the strings from both tables. Now I just need to figure out how I can create a new column to insert this information.

Comment: ***Update*** hmm.. I can't alter the table that 'mysql views' has created cuz it's just a 'view' not actual table?? I need to look into this a little more..

Answer (score 0):

With the Webform Rules and Rules modules (may require Tokens module), you may be able to concatenate the two field values for storage in your email field when the form is sumbitted.

Or, you might write a jQuery function to handle concatenation and fill of a hidden email field on the clientside.

Comment: Chad, I do have rules and tokens modules installed so I'll look into it see if it does what i need. thanks